# Probleme with the update of Sonata adminBundle

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, updating

i can't make update in sonata bundle ,i have only create or delete  in liste action please help !

[you can see with this that i have only the create or the delete action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z02wD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't override `configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)` function in your admin class, then you should have the `edit` route enabled.
In `configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)` function, put

```
 $listMapper->addIdentifier('name');
```

instead of

```
 $listMapper->add('name');
```

This will create a link on the name of your entity and you will be able to edit it.
Hope it helps! :)